# About copy property in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I tested this sample code.

Sample.h

```
 {

    NSString *string1;
    NSString *string2;
    NSMutableString *string3;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *string1;
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *string2;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableString *string3;

@end
```

Sample.m

```
#import "Sample.h"

@synthesize string1;
@synthesize string2;
@synthesize string3;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    string1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
    string2 = [[NSString alloc] init];
    string3 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
    string2 = string3;
    string1 = string3;
    [string3 appendString:@"test"];
    NSLog(@"%@",string1);
    NSLog(@"%@",string2);
    NSLog(@"%@",string3);

}

@end
```

The result is

```
2012-09-23 00:11:48.610 sample[13468:303] testtest
2012-09-23 00:11:48.611 sample[13468:303] testtest
2012-09-23 00:11:48.611 sample[13468:303] testtest
```

I think string2 should be "test" because the property is copy.
But string2 is "testtest".

```
string2 = [string3 copy];
```

This is the result I think.

```
string2 is "test"
```

Why?
Please tell me, I can't sleep well.

Comment: Where do you see any `copy` in your code or in your ivar attributes? I only see `strong` (which is the same as the `retain` keyword before ARC), not `copy`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're not accessing the properties but you're immediately manipulating the backing instance variables. For those ivars, the `=` operator is not special and *does not have the effect of invoking the setter method*, it's just a regular pointer assignment. So when you write

```
string2 = string3;
string1 = string3
```

then you assign the pointer to `string3` to both `string1` and `string2` - whatever you do with `string3`, it will be effective on the two other variables as well, because really, they point to **the very same string instance**.

What you have to do is one, declare your properties as `copy` instead of `strong`, two, write

```
self.string2 = string3;
self.string1 = string3
```

in order to invoke the setter methods and *actually* make *independent* copies of the strings.

P. s. By creating two empty instances of NSString using your

```
string1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
string2 = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

code and then reassigning something else to those variables, you're leaking memory.

Edit: you're lucky and you don't - by using ARC. With the old runtime, you would have wasted valuable bytes of your user's RAM.

But still. You don't need to create those instances - you're not directly `memcpy()`'ing the characters into preallocated memory. Please read a comprehensive tutorial on C pointers before diving deep into iOS development.

Comment: +1 for clearly explaining the difference between manipulating ivars directly, and accessing properties.

Comment: "you're leaking memory" - it appears he's using ARC though

Comment: @alanduncan ah yes, good find. I'm not using ARC though, so not sure if the reassignment would make the superfluously created NSString instances loose a refcount.

Comment: carbonic acid - I think LLVM inserts the release for you in that and similar instances under ARC

Comment: @alanduncan thanks, and +1 to your comment for knowing my proper name. :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you say the setter semantics on the `string2` property is `copy`.  You declared it `strong`.

You set the `NSString` pointer string2 to the `NSMutableString` pointer string3.  Then you proceeded to modify the mutable string pointed to by string3.  So you should expect string2 to reflect that.

This is, by the way, the primary reason why you **should** use `copy` setter semantics on objects that have mutable counterparts.